# Multiple different AJAX requests in one file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have this html code

```
<div class="a1"></div>
<div class="a2"></div>
<div class="a3"></div>
<div class="a4"></div>
<div class="a5"></div>
```

and i want to send ajax like this

```
   $.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: 'get.php',
 data: "id=" + "a1", // appears as $_GET['id'] @ your backend side
 success: function(data) {
       // data is ur summary
      $('#a1').html(data);
 }
    });
```

and get data from get.php for all [a1....a5] and get data to the div .

so i wanna ajax code to send and get all the [a1..a5] request in one javascript code i try to do it in loop but not work (i wasnt able to send request to get all the 5  data from get.php)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So, what's the problem then?

Comment: ah sorry , i mean i wanna a jax code to send and get all the [a1..a5] request in one javascript code i try to do it in loop but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple to accomplish, just put the code in a `for`-loop and it should work no problem:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'get.php',
    data: "id=a"+i, // <-- get a1...a5
    success: function(data) {
      $('.a'+i).html(data); // <-- save to Div with class a1...a5
    }
  });
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9fnt1kds/3) is a working fiddle.

Comment: Work thank you  (y) , and thanks also for @simão-lemos